# JazzHub and Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, ibm-cloud, devops, ibm-jazz

I am trying to do continuous delivery with my code on Bitbucket using Bluemix DevOps tools.
I am able to retrieve the code from Bitbucket to JazzHub but not in a continuous way. Note that I can create a webhook on Bitbucket but don't know where to find the jazzhub URL to use.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Try this link for getting the JazzzHub git url for your repo: https://hub.jazz.net/tutorials/jazzeditor/#push

Comment: Here is how you can do it with github - maybe this will help fill in some blanks: https://hub.jazz.net/gitHook/nielsbeens/MobileFirstForBleumix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuous delivery with Bitbucket and Bluemix is not available. For continous delivery on Bluemix, you need to use either Bluemix DevOps SCM or you can use github as per documentation https://hub.jazz.net/docs/reference/githubhooks/

Answer (score 0):

You could always use Codeship or Travis.Ci as the CI engine and publish your app to Bluemix like that.